# Jquery | How to fix if / else for the next script?

Tags: jquery

If the user is active, should appear: work / first div.

if not active (if nothing exists in the data), should appear: not work / second div.

How to fix it please?

*The users in the code is free, there is no sensitive information.

http://jsfiddle.net/rdcxozwn/3/

```
<button id="submit">Start</button>
<div class="work"></div>
<div class="notwork"></div>


var account = "**";
//if you type ** (not working account) its sould write 'not work' in the second div,
//but the else not working

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){

$.ajax({
url: "http://***/player_api.php?username=" + account + "&password=" + account + "&type=m3u",
success: function(response){

var data = response.user_info;

if (data.status.match("Active")){
$(".work").append("work\n");}
else{
$(".notwork").append("not work\n");}

}
});
});
});
```

Comment: So what is the issue here?

Comment: the else not append the 'not work'

Comment: Because the user is `Active`

Comment: the `data.status` is `Active` so you get `work` in that div `.work`

Comment: if you change the var to 'ali00' (not working account), its sould append to the second div. but its not working

Comment: Which var to ali00?

Comment: @azmir22 Try this way http://jsfiddle.net/rdcxozwn/11/

Comment: @azmir22 check the answer

Comment: var account = "ali00"; change the 01. i want to append to second div if its the word not Active

Comment: sec i check, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if `data.status` exist or not before further comparison, check `data.status && data.status.match("Active")` like:

```
if (data.status && data.status.match("Active")){
$(".work").append("work\n");}
else{
$(".notwork").append("not work\n");}
```

Here is the working link to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rdcxozwn/12/)